# bash/awk script extracts html metadata, need to remove whitespace and write to file

Tags: bash, awk, html-parsing, metadata

I've got a directory of html files courtesy of wget and I need to extract title tag and all metadata from each file -- but separately, so I can copy/paste into a spreadsheet (ok, if I were better at scripting this wouldn't be a requirement). I've got a script with two problems -- it produces lots of extra white space on the extraction and when I tried to write it to a file, the file was 600 GBs (no kidding, good thing I routed it to my external). I'm open to any solution native to *NIX. TIA for any help.

```
    #!/bin/bash
for LINE in `cat htmllist.txt`
do
   awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS="<title>|</title>";RS=EOF} {print $2}' $LINE
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you should get rid of all the lines with just white space.  You can do this by using awk like so:

```
cat <file> | awk '{ if (NF > 0) printf("%s\n", $0); }'
```

In your case, you could just pipe the last awk command into this one.
You could also get rid of multiple whitespaces in a row using awk.  Since they are the default separators you could do this:

```
cat <file> | awk '{
                    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                         printf("%s ", i);
                    }
                    printf("\n");
             }'
```

Comment: Thanks NOIP! piped it in behind, worked like a champ. I wonder if I could impose once more -- how to output to a file? The things I've tried don't work, obviously I haven't worked with awk a lot.

Comment: Issue with the titles not matching in number -- I suspect a newline in a few of the titles. Do you know of a way to get rid of newlines between title tags? Or adding in a file name or number to the file? thanks....

Comment: Sorry for the formatting - I don't know how to clean it up...  This code will do what I think you want.  However, it has a caveat attached to it.  It assumes that 2 title strings don't appear on the same line.

cat <file> | awk '
{
        if (match($0, ".*[^/]title.*/title")) {
                printf("%s\n", $0);
        } else if (match($0, "[^/]title")) {
                printf("%s", $0);
        } else if (match($0, "/title")) {
                printf("%s\n", $0);
        } else {
                printf("%s", $0);
        }
}'

Comment: Haven't ever seen two titles strings together so should be good. Thanks again for all your help, NOIP.

Comment: one more question, if you have the time...now need to get at metadata keywords with the script, <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2"> and I can't figure out how to target this string...

Comment: Although I was on deadline I took the time to look into html metadata processing using perl and libextractor -- I had a learning curve either way so better to use the right tool for the job.